# Java: Unable to fix unchecked conversion required java.util.Collection<? extends java.lang.String>

Tags: java, generics, vector, linkedhashset

I have a Vector of Strings, *oldV*, and want a second Vector that is identical but has all duplicates removed. The following works, in the sense that it compiles and results in Vector that has the duplicates removed:

```
Vector<String> newV = new Vector<String>( new LinkedHashSet(oldV) );
```

However, it generates two unchecked conversion warnings:

```
> warning: [unchecked] unchecked call to LinkedHashSet(java.util.Collection<? extends E>) as a member of the raw type java.util.LinkedHashSet

> warning: [unchecked] unchecked conversion
> found   : java.util.LinkedHashSet
> required: java.util.Collection<? extends java.lang.String>
```

In both cases, the ^ is positioned directly under the "new" in "new LinkedHashSet.

I'm at a loss of how to fix these warnings.

Comment: the set should use generics as well, new LinkedHashSet<String>(oldV)

Comment: morgano: Thanks! Works, and now makes sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `oldV` is declared as a `Vector<String>` just use the parameterized version of 'LinkedHashSet':

```
Vector<String> newV = new Vector<String>( new LinkedHashSet<String>(oldV) )
```

you can also use the annotation `@SuppressWarnings` if you just want to get rid of the warnings:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
Vector<String> newV = new Vector<String>( new LinkedHashSet(oldV) );
```